# How to build evpp in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, gcc, build, compiler-errors, linux-mint

I want to use [evpp library](https://github.com/Qihoo360/evpp) in my project but I cannot build it in my OS. My OS is Linux mint 18.1 and and I use the release build script in tools folder (release-build.sh). I am getting the following errors;

```
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/dns_resolver.cc:3:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/conn_pool.h:9:0,
                 from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/conn_pool.cc:1:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:590: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/httpc/conn_pool.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/httpc/conn_pool.cc.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:446: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/dns_resolver.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/dns_resolver.cc.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/conn.h:4:0,
                 from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/conn.cc:1:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:662: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/httpc/conn.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/httpc/conn.cc.o] Error 1
[ 42%] Linking C executable ../../../bin/benchmark_tcp_libevent_client
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/invoke_timer.cc:3:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:278: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/invoke_timer.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/invoke_timer.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/conn_pool.h:9:0,
                 from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/conn_pool.cc:1:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/tcp_server.h:4:0,
                 from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/tcp_server.cc:3:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:398: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/tcp_server.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/tcp_server.cc.o] Error 1
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:590: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/httpc/conn_pool.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/httpc/conn_pool.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/fd_channel.cc:7:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/fd_channel.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/fd_channel.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc:6:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:494: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/http/http_server.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/http/http_server.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.cc:5:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:134: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/event_loop.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/event_loop.cc.o] Error 1
[ 42%] Built target benchmark_ioevent_libevent
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/udp/udp_server.cc:3:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/conn_pool.h:9:0,
                 from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/request.cc:3:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:686: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/httpc/request.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/httpc/request.cc.o] Error 1
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:566: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/udp/udp_server.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/udp/udp_server.cc.o] Error 1
[ 42%] Linking C executable ../../../bin/benchmark_http_libevent
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/conn_pool.h:9:0,
                 from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/request.cc:3:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:686: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/httpc/request.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/httpc/request.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.cc:5:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:134: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/event_loop.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/event_loop.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/conn.h:4:0,
                 from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/response.cc:3:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/service.cc:5:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:470: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/http/service.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/http/service.cc.o] Error 1
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:614: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/httpc/response.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/httpc/response.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/listener.cc:4:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop_thread_pool.cc:3:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:302: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/event_loop_thread_pool.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/event_loop_thread_pool.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_watcher.cc:7:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:182: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/event_watcher.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/event_watcher.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/tcp_client.h:4:0,
                 from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/tcp_client.cc:5:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/dns_resolver.cc:3:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/tcp_server.h:4:0,
                 from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/tcp_server.cc:3:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop_thread_pool.cc:3:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:350: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/listener.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/listener.cc.o] Error 1
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:302: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/event_loop_thread_pool.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/event_loop_thread_pool.cc.o] Error 1
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:398: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/tcp_server.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/tcp_server.cc.o] Error 1
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:446: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/dns_resolver.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/dns_resolver.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_watcher.cc:7:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:182: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/event_watcher.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/event_watcher.cc.o] Error 1
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/tcp_client.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/tcp_client.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/connector.cc:4:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/invoke_timer.cc:3:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/fd_channel.cc:7:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:278: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/invoke_timer.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/invoke_timer.cc.o] Error 1
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/fd_channel.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/fd_channel.cc.o] Error 1
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:374: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/connector.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/connector.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/service.cc:5:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:470: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/http/service.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/http/service.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/tcp_client.h:4:0,
                 from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/tcp_client.cc:5:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/connector.cc:4:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop_thread.cc:3:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
compilation terminated.
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/listener.cc:4:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:206: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/event_loop_thread.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/event_loop_thread.cc.o] Error 1
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:374: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/connector.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/connector.cc.o] Error 1
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/tcp_client.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/tcp_client.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/tcp_conn.cc:7:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:326: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/tcp_conn.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/tcp_conn.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop_thread.cc:3:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/conn.h:4:0,
                 from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/conn.cc:1:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:662: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/httpc/conn.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/httpc/conn.cc.o] Error 1
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:206: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/event_loop_thread.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/event_loop_thread.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/conn.h:4:0,
                 from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/httpc/response.cc:3:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:350: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/listener.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/listener.cc.o] Error 1
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:614: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/httpc/response.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/httpc/response.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc:6:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/build.make:494: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/http/http_server.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/http/http_server.cc.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/udp/udp_server.cc:3:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/tcp_conn.cc:7:0:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/event_loop.h:22:45: fatal error: concurrentqueue/concurrentqueue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
compilation terminated.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:326: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/tcp_conn.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/tcp_conn.cc.o] Error 1
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/build.make:566: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/udp/udp_server.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/udp/udp_server.cc.o] Error 1
[ 42%] Built target benchmark_tcp_libevent_client
[ 42%] Built target benchmark_http_libevent
[ 42%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/benchmark_gettimeofday
[ 42%] Linking CXX executable ../../../../bin/example_recipes_self_control_timer_basic_02
[ 42%] Built target benchmark_gettimeofday
[ 42%] Linking CXX executable ../../../../bin/example_recipes_self_control_timer_basic_01
[ 42%] Built target example_recipes_self_control_timer_basic_02
[ 42%] Built target example_recipes_self_control_timer_basic_01
[ 43%] Linking CXX executable ../../../../bin/example_recipes_self_control_timer_periodic_04
[ 43%] Linking CXX executable ../../../../bin/example_recipes_self_control_timer_cancel_03
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_boost.dir/build.make:278: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_boost.dir/invoke_timer.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_boost.dir/invoke_timer.cc.o] Error 4
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc: In member function ‘void evpp::http::Server::Stop()’:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc:174:44: warning: lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
         auto fn = [&count, &promise, this, hs = lt.hservice]() {
                                            ^
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_boost.dir/build.make:470: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_boost.dir/http/service.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_boost.dir/http/service.cc.o] Error 1
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc: In member function ‘void evpp::http::Server::Pause()’:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc:214:19: warning: lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
         auto f = [hs = lt.hservice]() {
                   ^
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc: In member function ‘void evpp::http::Server::Continue()’:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc:225:19: warning: lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
         auto f = [hs = lt.hservice]() {
                   ^
evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_static.dir/build.make:614: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_static.dir/httpc/response.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_static.dir/httpc/response.cc.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:282: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:319: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_concurrentqueue_static.dir/all] Error 2
[ 43%] Built target example_recipes_self_control_timer_periodic_04
[ 43%] Built target example_recipes_self_control_timer_cancel_03
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc: In member function ‘void evpp::http::Server::Stop()’:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc:174:44: warning: lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
         auto fn = [&count, &promise, this, hs = lt.hservice]() {
                                            ^
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc: In member function ‘void evpp::http::Server::Pause()’:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc:214:19: warning: lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
         auto f = [hs = lt.hservice]() {
                   ^
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc: In member function ‘void evpp::http::Server::Continue()’:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc:225:19: warning: lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
         auto f = [hs = lt.hservice]() {
                   ^
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc: In member function ‘void evpp::http::Server::Stop()’:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc:174:44: warning: lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
         auto fn = [&count, &promise, this, hs = lt.hservice]() {
                                            ^
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc: In member function ‘void evpp::http::Server::Pause()’:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc:214:19: warning: lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
         auto f = [hs = lt.hservice]() {
                   ^
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc: In member function ‘void evpp::http::Server::Continue()’:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc:225:19: warning: lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
         auto f = [hs = lt.hservice]() {
                   ^
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc: In member function ‘void evpp::http::Server::Stop()’:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc:174:44: warning: lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
         auto fn = [&count, &promise, this, hs = lt.hservice]() {
                                            ^
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc: In member function ‘void evpp::http::Server::Pause()’:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc:214:19: warning: lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
         auto f = [hs = lt.hservice]() {
                   ^
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc: In member function ‘void evpp::http::Server::Continue()’:
/home/reza/Downloads/evpp-0.6.1/evpp/http/http_server.cc:225:19: warning: lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
         auto f = [hs = lt.hservice]() {
                   ^
[ 43%] Linking CXX static library ../lib/libevpp_lite_static.a
[ 43%] Built target evpp_lite_static
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:245: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_boost.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_boost.dir/all] Error 2
[ 44%] Linking CXX static library ../lib/libevpp_boost_static.a
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:134: recipe for target 'evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_static.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [evpp/CMakeFiles/evpp_static.dir/all] Error 2
[ 44%] Built target evpp_boost_static
[ 44%] Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libevpp.so
[ 44%] Built target evpp
[ 44%] Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/benchmark_tcp_asio_server
[ 44%] Built target benchmark_tcp_asio_server
[ 44%] Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/benchmark_tcp_asio_client
[ 44%] Built target benchmark_tcp_asio_client
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I installed all third-part libraries like boost, glog and gtest [look here](https://github.com/Qihoo360/evpp/blob/master/docs/quick_start.md). Am I missing something?

Comment: WHich parts of  https://github.com/Qihoo360/evpp/blob/master/docs/quick_start.md have you done ?

Comment: @nos I have installed all dependencies and run the release build script. I think I am missing something, maybe a library. Have you ever used this library?

Comment: It sounds like [concurrentqueue](https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue) is not installed. Please state your working directory, the location of concurrentqueue, and the exact commands you entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked my problem in Github. Please refer to the following page for the answer.
[Issue Solved](https://github.com/Qihoo360/evpp/issues/53)